# How to validate empty and not repeated jsf

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I am working in jsf with primefaces, and i have a dialog with an input text and a button to save and to cancel.
I want to check if the content of the input is empty and if it is contained into the database, and if any of these its true, shows a message of error

I have tried this to the empty validation but i can't do the other

```
oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('dlgAnadir').hide()"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, read [tour] and [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question\

Comment: If you want to show jsf validation, use `required = true` property in textbox. By the way, what you referred  here "if it is contained into the database, and if any of these its true, shows a message of error"